Endpoint added in apache airflow plugin not accessible

I'm experimenting with apache airflow for a project, installed
standalone version ( 2.9.0 ).  I have tired add a new custom endpoint
in airflow by using a custom plugin.

I have created a folder 'plugins' in ~/airflow, also added init.py in plugins directory
And the directory structure is as follows( not listed all the files and directories here)
airflow
  airflow.cfg
 - dags
 - plugins

Added the following in a new python file in plugins
vi test.py
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from flask import Blueprint, jsonify

# Define a Blueprint for your custom endpoint
custom_endpoint_bp = Blueprint('custom_endpoint', __name__)


# Define the endpoint function
@custom_endpoint_bp.route('/api/custom_endpoint', methods=['GET'])
def custom_endpoint():
    # Here I will add logic to add dags dynamically.
    data = {'message': 'This is a custom endpoint'}
    return jsonify(data), 200


# Define a custom plugin to register the Blueprint
class CustomPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = 'custom_plugin'
    flask_blueprints = [custom_endpoint_bp]

After restarting the instance I have tried

http://My_IP:PORT/api/custom_endpoint

But its giving 404 error page.
But when I tried command in shell, the plugin is listing, though its not listing in airflow> admin > plugins.
airflow plugins
name                          flask_blueprints                                            source
custom_plugin | <flask.blueprints.Blueprint:name='custom_endpoint' import_name='test'>           | $PLUGINS_FOLDER/test.py

Help me to identify the issues with the implementation. Is it possible to create a new endpoint in airflow by the method I followed?
Thanks in advance.

Not sure if it just a typo but actual python file should be __init__.py to create a python module

Its the issue with the standalone version, Its working perfect with docker version
